# catching accent characters from user input in objective-c code

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the code below that takes inout from users and determines if the `operator` is one of `+, -, *, /`and if not prints `unknown operator`. Now it works well except when I enter the `ˆ` character then the program just hangs no output is seen. I am feeling the code doesn't see `ˆ` as a valid character. How can I make my code see `ˆ`. Remember I am new to objective-c and my example is from a tutorial I am following.

```
//
//  main.m
//  ex-6.8
//
//  Created by george on 30/06/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 george. All rights reserved.
//  Program to evaluate simple expressions of the
//  form number operator number

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Calculator : NSObject
{
    double accumulator;
    //char operator;
}

// accumulator methods
- (void) setAccumulator: (double) value;
- (void) clear;
- (double) accumulator;

// arithmetic methods

- (void) add: (double) value;
- (void) subtract: (double) value;
- (void) multiply: (double) value;
- (void) divide: (double) value;

@end


@implementation Calculator
- (void) setAccumulator:(double)value
{
    accumulator = value;
}

- (void) clear
{
    accumulator = 0;
}

- (double) accumulator
{
    return accumulator;
}

- (void) add: (double) value
{
    accumulator += value;
}

- (void) subtract:(double)value
{
    accumulator -= value;
}

- (void) multiply:(double)value
{
    accumulator *= value;
}

- (void) divide:(double)value
{
    if( value != 0.0)
        accumulator /= value;
        else{
            NSLog(@"Division by zero.");
            accumulator = NAN;
        }
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        double value1, value2;
        char operator;
        Calculator *deskCalc = [[Calculator alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Type in your expression.");
        scanf("%lf %c %lf", &value1, &operator, &value2);


        [deskCalc setAccumulator:value1];

        switch (operator) {
            case '+':
                [deskCalc add: value2];
                NSLog(@"%.2f", [deskCalc accumulator]);
                 break;
            case '-':
                [deskCalc subtract: value2];
                NSLog(@"%.2f", [deskCalc accumulator]);
                break;
            case '*':
                [deskCalc multiply: value2];
                NSLog(@"%.2f", [deskCalc accumulator]);
                break;
            case '/':
                [deskCalc divide: value2];
                NSLog(@"%.2f", [deskCalc accumulator]);
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"Unknown operator.");
                break;
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should show the code you're trying.  I took the code posted here and added a `power` method.  Worked fine using `^` as the operator.

Comment: @Avi, This is the code i am trying would love to see the one you came up with.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't process a caret (`^`) operator.  If that's the code you're trying, you'll always get "Unknown operator.".

Comment: The point is to show `unknown operator` but in my code which I have posted here the program stalls and nothing prints to the console. Every other character works except `ˆ`character

Comment: I don't know.  What you posted works perfectly for me.

Comment: Which keyboard layout do you use and how do you type `^`? Maybe the ^ is waiting for another character to form î or â.

Comment: perhaps its a machine thing. But every other entry gives either `result output if one of '-, +, /, *'` or `unknown operator` except `ˆ`character which just hangs with no `unknown operator` display.

Comment: @Willeke, using mac in a vmware with windows keyboard, perhaps thats why.